# Empty for loop behavior in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to test for loop behavior in node.js. In Javascript/node.js for loop is synchronous but what if their is no statement in the loop.

For Example:

```js
console.log("START")
for(var i=0; i<100000000;i++){
}
console.log("END")
```

When i run above code in node.js it just prints:

```
START
END
```

And the execution completes.

But if there is a statement in the loop, it executes complete loop and then ends:

```js
console.log("START")
for(var i=0; i<100000000;i++){
   console.log("LOOP "+i);
}
console.log("END")
```

The output is:

```
START
LOOP 0
LOOP 1
....
....
....
LOOP 99999999
END
```

So what happens if there is no statement in the `for` loop in `node.js`?

Comment: It would run as if the loop is executed. where you think it's wrong?

Comment: Is this a trick question?

Comment: @appleapple No, when there is no statement in loop, it just don't execute.

Comment: @BenSteward Yes its tricky question.

Comment: @Kaiido yes may be.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong, they will not remove it because they still need to increment `i`.

Comment: @OnkarJanwa how you check that? I see no difference on output. Did you infer the CPU instructions? or put breakpoint with no stop?

Comment: How is this related to node.js?

Comment: @awesomeguy Run both the code in node.js and in browser, you will see the difference.

Comment: But you yourself stated "Javascript/node.js"

Answer (score 0):

Even if there's no statement, yes, there are still some calculation like *initialization*, *condition*, and/or *final-expression*.

Besides, sometimes people do use for without a statement. You can take a look at [MDN: Using for without a statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Using_for_without_a_statement).

Answer (score -2):

Finally i got it. For loop is always synchronous whether it is JavaScript or Node.js. And node.js does not skip an empty loop.

Executed below code:

```
console.log("START")
for(var i=0; i<10000000000;i++){
}
console.log(i);
console.log("END")
```

The output is:

```
START
10000000000
END
```

Comment: The difference is running length of the loop. You won't see any time take in the loop running if the length is small.